# SQL Server query JSON Array

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json

I am trying to query some JSON in SQL Server 2016 with the below structure where I would like to find all records where the 'key' has a certain value. Any help on how to do this?

```
{
    "nodeDataArray": [{
        "key": "5B502176-E51A-48B7-B8F0-350984CFBCF2",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, {
        "key": "1260263E-6111-47B2-9776-FE9BA5C90DCB",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, {
        "key": "8AE454D3-944E-47BE-8CA9-049318DE213B",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, {
        "key": "96B20972-F88C-44BA-84AA-C1F45BE5C7D5",
        "category": "IFM"
    }
    }]
}
```

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: What SQL Server version do you use? Is the query guaranteed to run on this version?

Comment: If you post code or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: SQL Server Version 2016

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @json = N'{
    "nodeDataArray": [  
    {
       "key": "5B502176-E51A-48B7-B8F0-350984CFBCF2",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, 
    {
        "key": "1260263E-6111-47B2-9776-FE9BA5C90DCB",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, 
    {
        "key": "8AE454D3-944E-47BE-8CA9-049318DE213B",
        "category": "IFM"
    }, 
    {
        "key": "96B20972-F88C-44BA-84AA-C1F45BE5C7D5",
        "category": "IFM"
    }
]
}'

SELECT  
    JSON_VALUE(nda.value, '$.key') AS [key],
    JSON_VALUE(nda.value, '$.category') AS [category]
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.nodeDataArray') AS nda
WHERE  JSON_VALUE(nda.value, '$.key')   = '1260263E-6111-47B2-9776-FE9BA5C90DCB'
```

Comment: Close, but this is not the same structure I had. I had an array of nodeDataArray which contained the values...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tj.*
FROM TableName t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (t.JsonColumn, '$.nodeDataArray')
  WITH (
    key VARCHAR(300) '$.key',
    category VARCHAR(300) '$.category'
  ) AS tj
```

Source: [Microsoft SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL 2016, have a look at this article: 
[JSON Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server).

If you are not on SQL 2016, there is no native JSON support. Your best bet would be to write something in .NET and call it from a SQL SP or function (Google can help you get started with this).

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2016. The issue really is around direct querying the DB to find all records (we have several hundreds of records with JSON data in them) which contain a certain value for key. The syntax for that is not clear to me. I could write a .Net function to do this of course but was wondering if I could simply send off a query to get the information for me...