# SQL JSON Query -retrieve data within a JSON array

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, json-query, json-value

I have the following SQL "Product" table structure:

```
int Id
nvarchar(max) Details
```

Details contains JSON a string having the following structure:

```
{
"Id": "10001",
"Description": "example description",
"Variants": [{
        "Title": "ABC / no",
        "Price": "10"
    }, {
        "Title": "ABC / Yes",
        "Price": "20",
    }, {
        "Title": "ABC / Yes",
        "Price": "30",
    }]
}
```

I need to write an SQL Query that would look through the table and return all the Variants with a particular title.

---

**The following work**

Get all rows from the table whose Details field contains a specific title

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.Description') = 'example description'
```

Get all rows from the table where Details.Variants[0].Title is equal to '{string}'

```
SELECT * FROM Products 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.Variants[0].Title') = 'ABC / no'
```

Get all **Ids** from the table where Details.Variants[0].Title is equal to '{string}'

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.Id') 
FROM Products 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.Variants[0].Title') = 'ABC / no'
```

---

**I need to get all Variants from all rows in the Product table, where the Variant title is equal to '{string}'**

There is a similar example in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#QUERY)  but I can't get it to work for my particuar case.

There is also this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055471/sql-server-query-json-array)

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @JimMacaulay SqlExpress - version 15.0.2000.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (columns definitions) and additional `APPLY`s to parse the input JSON and get the expected results. Note, that you need to use `AS JSON` option to specify that the `$.Variants` part of the stored JSON is a JSON array.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (Id int, Details nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Details)
VALUES (1, N'{"Id":"10001","Description":"example description","Variants":[{"Title":"ABC / no","Price":"10"},{"Title":"ABC / Yes","Price":"20"},{"Title":"ABC / Yes","Price":"30"}]}"')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT p.Id, j1.Id, j1.Description, j2.Title, j2.Price
FROM Products p
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (p.Details, '$') WITH (
    Id int '$.Id',
    [Description] nvarchar(100) '$.Description',
    Variants nvarchar(max) '$.Variants' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.Variants) WITH (
    Title nvarchar(100) '$.Title',
    Price nvarchar(10) '$.Price'
) j2
WHERE 
   j2.Title = 'ABC / no'
   -- or j1.Description = 'example description'
```

Result:

```
Id  Id      Description         Title       Price
1   10001   example description ABC / no    10
```