# Parse JSON in table with multiple ids

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have this JSON array, which is stored in an SQL Server table column named `[json]`. The table only has this one column.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  [json] nvarchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES('[{"Id":1},{"Id":2},{"Id":3}]');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ec7125b6bc7f66721821a40d51c684c)*

Output I need: Each Id in a separate row under the same column using a SELECT statement:

```
Id (column name)
----------------
1
2
3
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE([json], '$.Id') as Id
FROM table
```

But the result was empty:

```
Id   
--------
null
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @matt_vice89 - I updated the question to demonstrate a minimal example. Including that kind of example in future questions will make it easier to answer, and help avoid being closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server query JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055471/sql-server-query-json-array)  In Short, use CROSS APPLY with OPENJSON https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=958961cf2dbd7c6f1b7551a4365313b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's faily simple to get this using OpenJson with a WITH to identify the object you want to retrieve

```
declare @json  NVarChar(2048) = N'[{"Id":1},{"Id":2},{"Id":3}]';
SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json)
WITH (ID INT '$.Id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENJSON with JSON_VALUE like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  [json] nvarchar(200)
);


INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('[{"Id":1},{"Id":2},{"Id":3}]'), ('[{"Id":1},{"Id":2},{"Id":3}]')


SELECT JSON_VALUE(a.[Value], '$.Id') Id 
FROM MyTable f
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (f.[json]) a
```